# Numeric Integration of Parametric Equation

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I have a line integral over a scalar field in the form of

$$
\int_{t=0}^{t=1} f(x(t),y(t)) \sqrt{(d x/d t)^2 + (d y/d t)^2} d t
$$

Function $f$ is

$$
f(x) = 0.5 \exp (-\gamma || x - m_1 ||^2) + 0.5 \exp (-\gamma || x - m_2 ||^2 )
$$

where $x$ is actually $x=[x,y]$ to fit the first equation. The $x(t),y(t)$ are cubic polynomials. I am basically trying to find the area under parametrized cubic curve over a scalar field defined by an RBF function.

However even at polynomial degree 3 and with a simple RBF function as seen above, the symbolic integration gets very hairy. I have to numerically integrate this, I was wondering about the best approaches for that. Quick idea is dividing $t$ into N blocks, and make $dt = 1/N$, get $x,y$ from $t$, do the multiplication, sum, do this $N$ times, we are done.

Is this feasible? Should I use trapezoidal integration, or other methods for this?

Comment: There are *many* numerical methods. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration) for an introduction, and the bibliography of this article for some good references (notably Davis & Rabinowitz and Bulirsch & Stoer).

Comment: It might be easiest to just plug this into some mathematical software and tell it to numerically integrate. Quite often the software will already come up with a good way to do it by itself.

Comment: Hmm, I guess you mean something like this -  https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.6/modules/mpmath/calculus/integration.html - I was looking into numpy.trapz which takes in a list of already computed values, but this way could be easier. Thanks,